# Definition of Tensor Laplacian

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

Let $(M,g)$ be an orientable Riemannian manifold, $\nabla$ its Levi-Civita connection and $\epsilon$ its volume form. Let $f\in C^\infty(M)$ be a scalar field. Then we know that we can define its Laplacian by $$\nabla^2f=\star d\star df.\tag{1}$$

Now let $T \in \Gamma(T_k^0M)$ be a tensor field $$T:\Gamma(TM)\times\cdots \times \Gamma(TM)\to C^\infty(M),\tag{2}$$
how does one define the Laplacian $\nabla^2 T$? I've googled about it and the only thing I found was [this page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TensorLaplacian.html) and unfortunatelly I didn't manage to make sense of it because I found their notation quite confusing (I've never got used to that semicolon notation for covariant derivatives and, moreover, the rule I know is to sum over indices repeated indices appearing *twice*, and in their notation the same index appears even thrice).

Comment: More general keywords might help: "Laplacian of a connection on a vector bundle". For example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890919/connection-laplacian-on-general-vector-bundles

Comment: There are a couple of different "Laplacians" in differential geometry. Depending on your background, you might enjoy the exposition in Peter Petersen's Riemannian Geometry (pages 209-211). He discusses there the connection Laplacian  and the Hodge Laplacian invariantly (without semicolons :) and describes the connection between them.

Answer (score 7):

I've only recently read up on this stuff, so take everything here with a grain of salt. What we can do is try to mimic the idea that the Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient. So, we first define these two operations.

---

**Defining "the" Gradient.**

First, we address the gradient. Given a $(p,q)$ tensor field $T$, the covariant derivative $\nabla T$ will be a $(p, q+1)$ tensor field. Using the metric $g$'s musical isomorphism, we can construct a $(p+1,q)$ tensor field. For the lack of a more creative name, I'll call it $\text{grad}(T)$. So,
\begin{align}
[\text{grad}(T)](\omega_1, \dots \omega_p, \omega, X_1, \dots, X_q) &:= \left(\nabla_{g^{\sharp}(\omega)}T\right)(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_p, X_1, \dots, X_q)
\end{align}
where the $\omega$'s are covector fields, and $X$'s are vector fields. Or in components,
\begin{align}
[\text{grad}(T)]^{i_1 \dots i_p, a}_{j_1 \dots j_q} &= \left(\nabla_{g^{as}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^s}}T \right)^{i_1 \dots i_p}_{j_1 \dots j_q} = g^{as}\left(\nabla_sT \right)^{i_1 \dots i_p}_{j_1 \dots j_q}.
\end{align}
In the case of a smooth function $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ this gives us that $\text{grad}(f) = g^{\sharp}(df)$, so it is indeed the vector field "associated" to $df$ via the metric.

---

**Defining "the" Divergence.**

Next, we consider the divergence. Let $T$ be any $(p,q)$ tensor field with $p \geq 1$. Then, $\nabla T$ will be a $(p, q+1)$ tensor field, and we can take a trace with respect to the last covariant and contravariant slots to end up with a $(p-1, q)$ tensor field, which we call $\text{div}(T)$: 
\begin{align}
[\text{div}(T)](\omega_1, \dots \omega_{p-1}, X_1, \dots, X_q) &:= \text{trace} \bigg((\omega,X) \mapsto (\nabla T) \left(\omega_1, \dots, \omega_{p-1}, \omega, X_1, \dots, X_q, X \right) \bigg)
\end{align}
where the trace of a $(1,1)$ tensor (field) is of course well-defined and chart/basis/coordinate independent. So, in components, it is given by
\begin{align}
[\text{div}(T)]^{i_1 \dots i_{p-1}}_{j_1 \dots j_q} &= (\nabla_sT)^{i_1 \dots i_{p-1},s}_{j_1 \dots j_q}
\end{align}

---

**Defining "the" Laplacian**

So, we can now define a Laplacian of any $(p,q)$ tensor field by:
\begin{align}
\text{Lap}(T) &:= \text{div}(\text{grad}(T)).
\end{align}
This makes sense because $\text{grad}(T)$ will be a $(p +1, q)$ tensor field, so we can take its divergence to get a $(p,q)$ tensor field again.

For smooth functions, this definition of the Laplacian yields, in coordinates,
\begin{align}
\text{Lap}(f) &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^a} \left( \sqrt{|g|}\, g^{as} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^s}\right),
\end{align}
and assuming I didn't make any sign mistakes in my calculation, I'm pretty sure it also coincides with the definition you gave: $\star d (\star df)$.

---

For the definition of divergence, I used the one presented in Sachs and Wu's General Relativity book. Here are some observations I made: the definition of gradient required us to "raise" one of the indices, and I simply chose the last one. Similarly, the definition of divergence requires us to choose a certain pair of covariant and contravariant indices to take the trace over; once again I chose (as in the book) the last two. If the tensor $T$ is symmetric, then it of course doesn't matter which ones we choose. If it is not symmetric, then I haven't really carefully considered how it affects the definitions.

Finally, I'm no expert in this, so I'm not sure how exactly this relates to other definitions you might find.