# How to prove $\mathcal{K}:\nabla \nabla T$ = $ k \cdot \nabla^2 T$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, products

I'm trying to demonstrate that:
$\mathcal{K}:\nabla \nabla T$ == $ k \cdot \nabla^2 T$
where $\mathcal{K}$ is a second-order tensor.

Considering that:

\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{K} = kI
 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

$k$ is constant, and $I$ is the identity tensor (second-order).

I know that $\nabla\nabla T = \nabla^2 T$ which means that if:

$\mathcal{K}:\nabla \nabla T = k \cdot \nabla^2 T$

Then the double dot product "$\mathcal{K}:$" has to be equal to the dot product "$kI \cdot$" with $\nabla^2T$ but I don't know how to demonstrate that.

Comment: Won't $\nabla\cdot\mathcal{K}=0$? Then $\mathcal{K}:\nabla^2T=\sum_{i,j}\mathcal{K}_{ij}\partial_i\partial_jT=k\Delta T$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that by
$$\mathbf K:\nabla\nabla \mathbf T$$
Taking $T$ to be a $(p,q)$ tensor, that you mean, in indices,
$$K^{lm}\nabla_l\nabla_mT^{i_1\dots i_p}{}_{j_1\dots j_q}$$
I will stick to the case of $T$ being a $(2,0)$ tensor, but this generalizes with no problems.

The equation $\mathbf K=k\mathbf I$ means
$$K^i{}_j=k\delta^i_j$$
Equivalently we can raise an index
$$K^{ij}=kg^{ij}$$
So
$$(K:\nabla\nabla T)^{ij}=K^{lm}\nabla_l\nabla_mT^{ij} \\ =kg^{lm}\nabla_l\nabla_m T^{ij}$$
But of course $g^{lm}\nabla_l=\nabla^m$ hence
$$(K:\nabla\nabla T)^{ij}=k \nabla^m\nabla_m T^{ij}=k\Delta T^{ij}$$
Since $\nabla^m\nabla_m=\Delta$ [by definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4085545/is-this-a-contravariant-derivative-tensor-laplacian).